# How to use $ref in an example declaration in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

I'm using OpenAPI for a project.

I have a schema "campaign" and another schema "campaign_collection", that is just a collection of the first one (plus a few additional meta fields).

campaign_collection schema:

```yaml
campaign_collection:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/meta_fields'
    - type: object
      properties:
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/campaign'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/collection_meta_fields'
```

This works just fine. But, when I'm using examples, I'd like to use my Campaign example inside my campaign_collection example, something like this:

campaign_collection example:

```yaml
campaign_collection:
  value:
    # A few meta fields...
    items:
      - $ref: '#/components/examples/campaign'
    # A few more meta fields...
```

But, it doesn't work, it renders like this in Swagger UI:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/examples/campaign"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I use `$ref` to make a reference to another example inside an example? I'd like to keep my campaign collection example up to date with my campaign example, instead of doing it manually. Can I do that in OpenAPI? Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like `example` (singular), the `examples.<name>.value` key does NOT support `$ref`. The entire example must be specified inline. The contents of the `value` key is taken and displayed as is.

There is no way to reference a part of an example.